# Adding header to ListView not matching parent in width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

The individual layout files look fine (`match_parent` actually fills parent), but when I try to set the header of the `ListView`, it behaves differently.

The way I see it is: the button's width, is matching its parent layout's width, not sure why this doesn't work.

Actual:

[image: Actual]]

Expected:

[image: xml]]

I couldn't get the code formatting here to work so here are pastebin links to them.

`header_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingTop="30dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/trackingHeader">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="0px"
           android:layout_height="0px"
           android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/start_service"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:text="Begin Tracking" />

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/stop_service"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/start_service"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:text="Cease Tracking" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/trackingStatus"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="Large Text"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:paddingTop="10dp"
           android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`content_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/trackingList"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    trackingHeader = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.header_layout, null);
    trackingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trackingList);
    trackingList.addHeaderView(trackingHeader, null, false);
```

Comment: Change `android:layout_width="0px"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`?

Comment: Are you talking about the one in header_layout.xml? I originally put that there to take away focus from some textboxes I had earlier. I have removed it and it had no effect

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was editing your question to proper formatting and I took that by mistake that it was your layout. Did you try changing your `ListView` width to `match_parent` ?

Comment: Oh that was it! I assumed it was already match_parent based on what it looked like. Want to post that answer so I could mark this question as solved?

Comment: I wasn't sure the answer, it was from logical deduction, so I posted it as comment instead of answer. I have added it as answer now. By solving your problem I realized how it works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width of header is the same as `ListView` attribute, so you need to change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/Hepj6KynZD5) and confirmed in the [documentation for `View.inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)), when you use `View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.header_layout, null)`, all of the `layout_` attributes on your topmost view are effectively ignored as you have not specified a parent - the default values for `layout_height` and `layout_width` are `wrap_content`.

Instead, you should be calling the [inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) method in [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), passing in the parent and `false` to not attach the View (as that's what `addHeaderView()` will do for you):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService
    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
trackingHeader = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
    R.layout.header_layout, trackingList, false);
```